# TypeError: $scope.elencoTicket is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use these angular js code in the controller:

```
 $scope.elencoTicket = function(){
        $http({method :"GET",
               url    :"./ajax/listaTicket.php",
               params : {cliente:$scope.cliente}})
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.elencoTicket=response.data;
        });
    }


$scope.chiudiTicket = function(idTicket){
    $http({method:"GET",
           url   :"./ajax/chiudiTicket.php",
           params:{idTicket:idTicket}})
    .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data);
          $scope.elencoTicket()})
    .catch(function(response){$scope.elencoTicket()});
}
```

The both of the call ajax works correctly, but at the end of the process i get this error message:
TypeError: $scope.elencoTicket is not a function

I can't understand where is it my mistake.
Some of you has some good advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to you override the `elencoTicket` function with the `response.data` here:

```
$scope.elencoTicket = function(){
        $http({method :"GET",
               url    :"./ajax/listaTicket.php",
               params : {cliente:$scope.cliente}})
        .then(function(response){
            // Here is the source of the error
            $scope.elencoTicket=response.data;

            // Solution: use another variable name
            $scope.responseData=response.data;
        });
    }
```